# Concrete Mathematics: Formulating definition for value of a general infinite sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I am having trouble following the explanation which I will reproduce below shortly. I think it is just saying if an infinite sum has a "bounding constant" such as the first example they give, $S = 1 + \frac12 + \frac14 + \frac18 + ...$ bounded by $2$ then them resulting sum is finite even if the "inputs" are infinite. If the sum has no bounding constant then the sum result is infinite.

Below is the paragraph to give context so I can highlight the part that confuses me:

> Let's try to formulate a good definition for the value of a general sum $\sum_{k\in K}$, where $K$ might be infinite. For starters, let's assume that all the terms $a_k$ are *nonnegative*. Then a suitable definition is not hard to find: If there's a bounding constant $A$ such that
>
> $$
> \sum_{k\in F}a_k \leq A
> $$

I think I get the above but then this last part I am not following:

> for all *finite* subsets $F \subset K$, then we define $\sum_{k \in K}a_k$ to be the *least* such $A$.

Is this a way of saying our sum will be $A$ big if that is the bounding constant? I don't understand what they mean by "the least such $A$".

Comment: If you look at $1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + \cdots$, there are many numbers which are an upper bound to *every* finite sum of these numbers. There’s $3, 10, 60$, etc. But $2$ is unique in that it is such an upper bound, but if you pick any number less than $2$ you can find a finite sum that will exceed it. Here $2$ is the least such $A$, and it makes sense to define the sum of other infinite sequences like that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the series
$$S=\dfrac12+\dfrac14+\dfrac18+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{2^k}+\cdots$$
The partial sums (the summations referred in the post) are $\frac12$, $\frac34$, $\frac78$, $\frac{9}{16}$, and so on. Now, you notice that all of these are less than $1$ (the bounding constant).

But observe that the partial sums are also always less than $2$, $3$, or even $2102\times10^{31}$. However, for any number less than $1$, you will always find a partial sum which exceeds that number. (Try proving that!) Hence, it follows $1$ is the least number satisfying this property. If we don't use it, we will be left with infinitely many $A$'s which wouldn't be any use of us then.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, if I understand correctly, we'll always find a partial sum that exceeds the infinite sum bounding constant? So, even if "partial sums" of just one term is always less than $1$, as soon as you add another term it is greater than $1$.

Comment: @Friedrich: As far as I remember, I replied to your comment. Maybe it's just me  forgetting things, never mind. I see you have accepted the answer. So you understood my points? The things you mentioned in the comment are not quite correct.

Comment: I _think_ I get the gist of it but would not mind some more details about what is not correct in my comment. All angles of explanation help me understand - for me learning new maths is like being in a dark room and explanations are like light beams. The more there are the better to understand the concepts.

Comment: @Friedrich: Consider a box full of very large number of apples, say a million. Each apple costs, say a dollar. Now, you can take any number of apples, any number. No matter how much of it you take out, the total price of those apples will always be less than a million dollars. (Yes, I know that this can be exactly that, but ignore that for now.) But if you notice, the price of all those apples is also always less than a billion dollars. Or any number of dollars greater than a million right?

Comment: Same goes with series except for it is infinite, and the cost is in such a way that even if you buy a infinite number of apples, you'll always have the cost less than a million. (Probably some weird discount, depending upon your number of purchases.) Now, note that your cost of apples is always less than (or equal to) a million, and any number greater than a million. A million is the smallest such cost, and we call that, the minimum bounding constant, as the value of the infinite series itself.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write those helpful explanations! I think what makes it make more sense for me is describing the bounding constant as the _minimum bounding constant_ i.e. that is the "handle" by which we describe the infinite sum.